# What would be the dimension of the vector space $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $C$ be $n \times n$ matrix over the real number field $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $W$ be the vector space spanned by the matrices

$$I, C,C^2,C^3, \ldots,C^{(2n)}.$$

What is the dimension of the vector space $W$ ?

---

Following the hint below, $C$ satisfies its own characteristic equation $$a_0I+a_1C+\cdots+a_nC^n=0.$$
So $\{I,C,C^2, \cdots, C^n \}$ is linearly dependent set and hence the rest matrices $C^{n+1}, C^{n+2}, \cdots, C^{2n}$  generate a vector space of dimension at most $n$.

So the answer should be atmost $n$.

Comment: Welcome to SE . Please make your question more clear ... Which part is the question ? Also, use mathjax and remember to write what you tried on every question

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Often with multiple choice questions, some answers can be eliminated by comparing the necessary implications between answers.  Even more effective in this particular case would be thinking of special cases and (perhaps) theorems about characteristic polynomials.

Comment: I have improved some of my old question in order to revive my account. If my question is perfect now please vote up the question

Comment: I have developed the question as much as possible. Can someone give reason why downvoted further ?

Comment: I appreciate this effort, and I think a reopening is justified here, but please do not beg for upvotes. I upvote it for the sake of motivation to continue with improving your old posts.

Comment: You have already accepted an answer, but you still don't know the answer to your question, do you?

Comment: @Filippo, I know the answer by the given hints but I didn't realise to improve the question at that time which bans me for asking more question in MSE. So I now realise to improve my old questions

Comment: @Peter, thanks for your comments. I understand it

Comment: OK so we can not determine the precise dimension without further information? We can only give an upper bound?

Comment: @Filippo, this was a multiple choice question and the options were  like "atmost n" etc.

Comment: @learner All right, thank you for the information! In this case, I think it would have been a good idea to mention this in your question and to write down all the options that were given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**:

Every square matrix satisfies its own *characteristic equation*.